# Trying to dynamically expand different divs with one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, slidetoggle

I'm trying to be able to dynamically expand / collapse multiple divs with the same code....

it's controlled with the click of a span (toggle) and then i'm trying to get the next id(the div that would slide up and down)

```
            $('span').toggle(
    function() {
$('#albumholder').slideToggle(600);
    $(this).html('-');},
    function() {
$('#albumholder').slideToggle(600);
    $(this).html('+');}

    );
```

This code works to expand 1 div... but assume i have a divs

```
#downloadholder
#linksholder
etc...
```

How can i achieve the same effect with the same code? Thanks!

**EDIT**

It's worth noting that I need each div to toggle independently.  If i click the plus button on the span that is affecting #albumholder, it should not expand #downloadholder or #linksholder

Answer (score 5):

Two ways -

add them in the selector

```
$('#downloadholder, #linksholder')
```

or add a class to those items

```
$('.toExpand')

<div id="downloadholder" class="toExpand" />
<div id="linksholder" class="toExpand" />
```

Rereading your question, it's perhaps you want to get the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) div?

```
$('#yourSpanElement').click(function() {
    $span = $(this);
    $yourDiv = $span.next('div');
   // do your magic :)
});
```

your code revamped:

```
$('span').toggle(
    function() {
      var $span = $(this);
      $span.next('div').slideToggle(600);
      $span.html('-');
    },      
    function() {
      var $span = $(this);
      $span.next('div').slideToggle(600);
      $span.html('+');
    }
 );
```

you could also check for the next divs appearance:

```
$('span').click(function() {
  var $span = $(this);
  var $nextDiv = $span.next('div');
  if( $nextDiv.is(':visible') ) {
     $nextDiv.slideUp(600);
     $span.html('+');
  }else {
     $nextDiv.slideDown(600);
     $span.html('-');
  }
});
```

Comment: this works, but it is effecting both divs... if i click either, they both toggle... i need to get each one to work independently.. thanks for your help so far

Comment: Updated the answer as you were commenting - something like that? you want the next div after the span?

Comment: yeah, i'd like to say okay... i have this span class if i click it, i want it to expand the NEXT div, because in all cases, the div that i want to expand will be directly after

Comment: then my answer should suit ya nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

Make you htmlr something like this.

```
<span toggletarget="downloadholder>+</span>
<div id="downloadholder"></div>
```

Then make your javascript

```
$('span[toggletarget]').click(function () {$(this).toggle(
function() {
    $("#"+$(this).attr("toggletarget")).slideToggle(600);
    $(this).html('-');},
function() {
$('#albumholder').slideToggle(600);
$(this).html('+');}
);});
```

Comment: That may be but, screw em' :)  I'd rather have w3c mad at me rather than make my code less readable.  I invent my own attributes because it's easier to manage from the server site this way. If all my javascript is based off of data posted onto the html then I can quickly and easily prepopulate from server data.